# Webhook - verification - OPTIONS method to verify if POST request are allowed - Integromat SDK

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

I need to verify a [Webhook Attach from Integromat SDK](https://docs.integromat.com/apps/app-structure/webhooks#attach)

The [GoToConnect Webhook registration aka NotificationChannel](https://developer.goto.com/GoToConnect/#section/Webhook) requires a response from an `OPTIONS` request to validate if it's allowing `POST` requests.

So, I write the Webhook definition using the Integromat SDK like below:

- **Webhook - `api.imljson`**

```
{
    "output": "{{body}}",
    "verification": {
        //"condition": "{{ if(headers.method == 'OPTIONS', true, false) }}",
        "condition": true,
        "respond": {
            "status": "200",
            //"type": "urlencoded",
            "body": {},
            "headers": {}
        }
    }
}
```

- **Webhook - `attach.imljson`**

```
{
    "url": "https://api.jive.com/notification-channel/v1/channels/{{parameters.channelNickname}}",
    "method": "POST",
    "body": {
        "channelType": "Webhook",
        "webhookChannelData": {
            "webhook": {
                "url": "{{webhook.url}}"
            }
        },
        //"channelLifetime": "{{ifempty(parameters.channelLifetime, 15552000)}}"
        "channelLifetime": "{{ parameters.channelLifetime }}"
    },
    "response": {
        "data": {
            "externalHookId": "{{body.channelId}}",
            "externalHookNickname": "{{body.channelNickname}}",
            "channelId": "{{body.channelId}}",
            "channelNickname": "{{body.channelNickname}}",
            "channelLifetime": "{{body.channelLifetime}}",
            "doNotDisturbAware": "{{body.doNotDisturbAware}}"
        }
    }
}
```

- **Webhook - `dettach.imljson`**

```
{
    "url": "https://api.jive.com/notification-channel/v1/channels/{{ webhook.channelNickname }}/{{ webhook.channelId }}",
    "method": "DELETE"
}
```

But it didn't work as expect

[image: print of app module webhook for GoToConnect NotificationChannel]

Is there a correct way to accomplish this verification of OPTIONS request?

Answer (score 0):

The support from Integromat reply to my opened ticket.

So, I was using a [Shared Webhook](https://docs.integromat.com/apps/app-structure/webhooks/shared) in the definition, and in this case, must be a [Dedicated Webhook](https://docs.integromat.com/apps/app-structure/webhooks/dedicated) because it has to send the URL from Integromat to register the webhook.